# Tableau: Can we find the values that user have entered through parameter during the month at the end entire month?

Tags: tableau-api

Suppose I had entered any value through parameter (weekly or daily), later at end of month Can Ifind the values that user have entered in that entire month?

Comment: Couldn't understand what is your requirement?

Comment: Voting to close the question unless some clarification is given.